# Dynamic xml text and Images wont refresh in Flash

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, caching

I have a simple flash landing page that has 2 areas that rotate images dynamically and 2 areas of dynamic text.  All areas are controlled from a single XML file.

When I make changes to the text content in the XML file or if I update the images in the folder and test in my adobe flash editor the changes are instant.  When I open firefox or IE the page with the flash file does not reflect the updates. I have deleted my history, told adobe flash to not permit any flash to be stored on my computer, closed and reloaded the pages but to no avail.  The only way I can get the content to be refreshed is to rename the file, save in new folder and rename the xml page it draws from.  I have even added the kiosk.swf?id=#randrange(10000,99999)# string at the end to see if it makes the browser think its a new file.   Nothing short of renaming and moving the files/folders will get browser to display the new content.

This simple flash page is ment to be a landing page at a kiosk.

```
    <style type="text/css" media="screen">
        body { margin:0; padding:0; overflow:hidden;background-color:#153d6f; }
        #myID   { height:100%;background-color:#153d6f; }
    </style>    
    <script type="text/javascript" src="swfobject.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="swffit.js"></script>
   <cfoutput>
       <script type="text/javascript">
            swfobject.embedSWF("kiosk.swf?id=#randrange(10000,99999)#", "myID", "100%", "100%", "9.0.0", "expressInstall.swf");
            swffit.fit("myID");
        </script>
   </cfoutput> 

</head>
<body>
    <div id="myID"></div>
</body>
```

...................
as per your request, the actionscript3 that pulls the dynamic images to one of the two areas
...................

```
import fl.transitions.Tween;
import fl.transitions.easing.*;
import fl.transitions.TweenEvent;


var my_speed:Number;
var my_total:Number;
var my_images:XMLList;

var my_loaders_array:Array = [];
var my_success_counter:Number = 0;
var my_playback_counter:Number = 0;

var my_slideshow:Sprite = new Sprite();
var my_image_slides:Sprite = new Sprite(); 

var my_timer:Timer;
var my_prev_tween:Tween; 

var my_xml_loader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
my_xml_loader.load(new URLRequest("content.xml")); 
my_xml_loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, processXML);




function processXML (e:Event):void{
    var my_xml:XML = new XML(e.target.data); 
    my_speed=my_xml.option2.slideShow2.@SPEED;
    my_images=my_xml.option2.slideShow2.IMAGE;
    my_total=my_images.length();    

    loadImages();
}

function loadImages():void{
    for (var i:Number = 0; i < my_total; i++){
        var my_url:String = my_images[i].@URL;
        var my_loader:Loader = new Loader();
        my_loader.load(new URLRequest(my_url));
        my_loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onComplete);
        my_loaders_array.push(my_loader); 
    }
}

function onComplete(e:Event):void{
    my_success_counter++;
    if (my_success_counter == my_total){
        startShow();
    }

}  

function startShow():void{
    addChild(my_slideshow);
    my_slideshow.addChild(my_image_slides);

    setChildIndex(my_slideshow,0);

    nextImage();

    my_timer = new Timer(my_speed*1000);
    my_timer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, timerListener);
    my_timer.start();


}

function nextImage():void{
    var my_image:Loader = Loader(my_loaders_array[my_playback_counter]);
    my_image_slides.addChild(my_image);
    //my_image.x = (stage.stageWidth - my_image.width)/2;
    //my_image.y = (stage.stageHeight - my_image.height)/2;


    if (my_image.width == my_image.height) {
        my_image.width = 305;
        my_image.height = 305;
    }   else if( my_image.width > my_image.height ) {
            var newWidth = (my_image.width *(305 / my_image.height));
            my_image.height = 305;  
            my_image.width = newWidth;
    }   else if( my_image.width < my_image.height ) {
            var newHeight = (my_image.height *(305 / my_image.width));
            my_image.width = 305;   
            my_image.height = newHeight;

    }

    my_image.x = 80;
    my_image.y = -140;


    new Tween(my_image,"alpha",Strong.easeOut,0,1,1,true); 



} 

function timerListener (e:TimerEvent):void{
    hidePrev();

    my_playback_counter++;
    if (my_playback_counter == my_total){
        my_playback_counter =0;
    }

    nextImage();

} 

function hidePrev():void{
    var my_image:Loader=Loader(my_image_slides.getChildAt(0));
    my_prev_tween = new Tween(my_image,"alpha",Strong.easeOut,1,0,1,true);
    my_prev_tween.addEventListener(TweenEvent.MOTION_FINISH, onFadeOut)

    new Tween(my_image,"alpha",Strong.easeOut,1,0,1,true);

} 

function onFadeOut(e:TweenEvent):void{
    my_image_slides.removeChildAt(0);

}
```

Comment: can you show the code from kiosk.swf? It loads the xmls, maybe you need to add that "cache killer" thing to it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To avoid caching in actionscript, add "?" and then some unique characters to the end of the URL for the item you are loading (be it images, swfs, xml, whatever). eg:

```
var cacheBuster:String = "?"+(new Date()).time.toString();
my_loader.load(new URLRequest(my_url+cacheBuster));
```

new Date().time returns number of millisecs since 1-1-1970, so its a good choice for generating a unique string.

If its kiosk.swf thats caching, the javascript is very similar:

```
var cacheBuster = "?"+(new Date()).getTime().toString();
swfobject.embedSWF("kiosk.swf"+cacheBuster, ....
```

Comment: this helped but it was also caching the xml file it read from, I added this code to both the swf and the xml links and it works just fine now. thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

for info about text visit [here](http://www.virtualmv.com/wiki/index.php?title=Flash10%3aActionScript2%3aImporting_XML_into_Dynamic_Text_Boxes)

for how to refresh your images visit [here](http://www.republicofcode.com/tutorials/flash/as3slideshow/)

hope this helps!

Comment: yes thanks for the links, spent time going through that tutorial prior to this project. (I was handed this project but flash is not my field)  Its pulling great when I test it in the adobe flash editor, and the first time I pull it up in the browsers it works great, but if I go in and change it after I first load it, none of the changes will show up.  Like its holding on to the file and content in cache.

Comment: here's a link for that http://www.flashxml.net/how-to-clear-your-browsers-cache.html

Comment: here is where I'm at on this issue. To test I downloaded the example from the link you posted about how to refresh your images. posted it to my server and am getting the same results.  I looked in my temp files to see if the "kiosk.swf?id=#randrange(10000,99999)#" was indeed forcing the browser to download it as new file, it was.  I deleted the content.xml file and it then was forced to download the updated content.xml file and the changes where updated.  Where I am at now is seeing that the browser is caching the xml file and not downloading the newest xml file.

Comment: I will find a way to make the browser NOT cache the xml file or in actionscript apend the content.xml file to todaysDateContent.xml and write a script that changes the name of the xml file on the server each morning. (clunky)  I shouldn't have to do that.  someone else must be experiencing this issue. o_O

Comment: i agree. it is a strange problem. sorry i couldn't be of more help :(

Comment: see this link and see if it helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3817429/dynamically-changing-the-referenced-xml-file-in-flash-as3

Comment: I found the issue, it was also caching the xml file... by adding the random number to the xml file as well as the swf file it resolved the issue. thx :)

Comment: hurrah! thank god that's fixed. do you upvote my answer now ;)